# Why my CSS animation is smooth only when I move my mouse on the iframe?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-variables

I'm encountering the same problem than the post [Why CSS animation go smooth only if i am moving mouse pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588180/why-css-animation-go-smooth-only-if-i-am-moving-mouse-pointer), **but only for stackoverflow snippets** (codepen and jsfiddle are working fine).

Problem is present on:

- Firefox 67.0.4 on Xubuntu 18.04
- Firefox 68.0.1 on Windows 10

I had no problem on:

- IE11 & Edge (not working at all :P)
- Chrome 75 on Windows 10

---

Now time for the demos:

- Here's the stackoverflow snippet (*also made a [video](https://up.l3m.in/file/1563978515-slow-animation.webm) in case you are not able to reproduce the bug*):

  ```css
  div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
  }

  span[data-id]::before{
    opacity: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 50px;
    content: attr(data-id);
    background-position: center;
    animation: fade 4s linear calc(1s * var(--data-x)) infinite;

  }

  @keyframes fade{
    25%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <span data-id="1" style="--data-x:0"></span>
    <span data-id="2" style="--data-x:1"></span>
    <span data-id="3" style="--data-x:2"></span>
    <span data-id="4" style="--data-x:3"></span>
  </div>
  ```
- Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32Lbvakx/) link.
- Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/lmmm/pen/GVZxYj) link.

---

My question is:
Can you explain me why there is a problem on the execution of an animation when browsing a specific snippet with a specific browser ? (*and are you able to reproduce this strange behaviour ?*)

Comment: I have the problem with all of them (codepen, jsfiddle and stackoverflow snippet) in firefox

Comment: Please add your code tot he question.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo What do you mean ?

Comment: Oops, i missed the snippet...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in Firefox 71, and noticed that the problem does exist on jsfiddle, but not on codepen. In addition to that, the iframe src url viewed by itself works properly: https://fiddle.jshell.net/32Lbvakx/show/

The surprising part is that the relevant code is still in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox removes CSS animation priority completely from small iframes (tested on firefox 71 in Ubuntu).

Right now, the codepen example uses over half the available screen when square, and animates properly: [image: codepen screenshot with large output area]

However, the codepen example stops animating without mouse movement as soon as the size of the iframe is less then half the size of the outer page:

[image: codepen screenshot with small output area]

If you resize the firefox window for codepen, you can actively see the effect of the animation halting as soon as the window size is too small. I don't see a bug on the firefox bugzilla on this specifically, but there are some bugs around animations in iframes that may be related.

Comment: I have filed a bug report on the firefox bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1608194

Comment: Wow, I never thought it could be a firefox bug! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. According to the helpful people at the bugzilla link above, it looks like this behavior is specifically tied to a bugfix from a couple years ago related to the "offscreen-throttling" feature. It can be disabled on a per-browser basis in the settings, but that won't help unknown site visitors.

Comment: Just adding a comment here to say that the bug was [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1608194#c7) 4 months ago (Apr 2020)!